# Array field Firestore query with prefix

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to query a Firestore collection to get all documents whose array filed has a specific prefix word?

for example,

User A
uid : uid000
region list : [ USA-CA, USA-NY]

User B
uid : uid001
region list : [ USA-ALL, EU-FR]

User C
uid : uid002
region list : [ASIA-JP, ASIA-CH]

when fetching the user list like above from Firestore and select 'USA-' to filter,
I want to get all users whose region list even has an element that starts with 'USA-'

result : userlist : [ User A, User B ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when fetching the user list like above from Firestore and selecting 'USA-' to filter, I want to get all users whose region list even has an element that starts with 'USA-'

No, you cannot achieve that using an array. However, if you're allowed to change the database structure a little bit, then you can achieve the same result. Since the `USA-` is the common element of those arrays, then you should consider naming the array like so:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
        |
        --- uid000 (document)
        |    |
        |    --- USA: ["CA", "NY"]
        |
        --- uid001 (document)
        |    |
        |    --- USA: ["ALL"]
        |    |
        |    --- EU: ["FR"]
        |
        --- uid002 (document)
             |
             --- ASIA: ["JP", "NY"]
```

To query the users who have the `USA` array present in the document, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("products").whereNotEqualTo("USA", null).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getId());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see we query against the `USA` field for existence. The result in the logcat will be:

```
uid000
uid001
```

Comment: Nice answer Alex.

Comment: Hi Alex long time no see. I have a new question! Could u please check this and give me answer??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74170121/android-kotlin-coroutine-callback-flow-awaitclose-error?noredirect=1#comment130954968_74170121