# android kotlin coroutine callback flow awaitClose error

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a coroutine flow with Firebase Realtime Database for asynchronous things but as you can see that error occurred after 4~5 seconds onCreate of the activity.

**Error**

[image]

**DataSourceImpl**

```
override fun observeMessage(roomUid: String): Flow < Map < Int, Response < MessageEntity >>> = callbackFlow {

  try {

    val reference = databaseReference.child("messages").child(roomUid)

    val subscription = reference.addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {

      override fun onChildAdded(

        snapshot: DataSnapshot,
        previousChildName: String ?

      ) {

        val message = snapshot.getValue(MessageEntity::class.java)

        if (message != null)
          trySend(mapOf(ADDED to Response.Success(message)))
        else
          trySend(mapOf(RESPONSE_NULL to Response.No(MessageEntity(uid = NULL))))

      }

      override fun onChildChanged(

        snapshot: DataSnapshot,
        previousChildName: String ?

      ) {

        val message = snapshot.getValue(MessageEntity::class.java)

        if (message != null)
          trySend(mapOf(CHANGED to Response.Success(message)))
        else
          trySend(mapOf(RESPONSE_NULL to Response.No(MessageEntity(uid = NULL))))

      }

      override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

      }

      override fun onChildMoved(

        snapshot: DataSnapshot,
        previousChildName: String ?

      ) {

      }

      override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

      }

    })

    awaitClose {

      reference.removeEventListener(subscription)
      channel.close()
    }

  } catch (exception: Exception) {
    trySend(mapOf(ERROR to Response.Error(exception.message.toString())))
  }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
private fun _observeMessage (roomUid: String) : Flow<Map<Int, Response<MessageEntity>>> {

  val flow = repository.observeMessage(roomUid).shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),0)

  return flow
}

fun observeMessage (roomUid: String) : Flow<Map<Int, Response<MessageEntity>>> {
  return _observeMessage(roomUid)
}
```

**Activity**

```
lifecycleScope.launch {


            viewModel.observeMessage(roomUid).collect { map ->

                val type = map.keys.first()

                val messageResponse = map[type]

                if (type == ADDED) {


                    when(messageResponse) {

                        is Response.Success -> {

                            val message = messageResponse.data


                            if (messageList.contains(message)) {


                                val index = messageList.indexOf(message)

                                messageList.set(index, message)

                            } else {
                                messageList.add(message)
                            }


                            // in case of other sent message and received it
                            if (!message.read && !message.sender.equals(ownUid)) {


                                val readMessageResponse = viewModel.readMessage(roomUid, message.uid)

                                when(readMessageResponse) {

                                    is Response.Success -> {

                                    }
                                    is Response.Error -> {

                                    }
                                    else -> {

                                    }
                                }


                            } else {

                                adapter.changeMessages(messageList)
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                            }


                        }
                        is Response.Error -> {

                        }
                        else -> {

                        }

                    }


                } else if (type == CHANGED) {

                    when(messageResponse) {

                        is Response.Success -> {

                            val message = messageResponse.data


                            val index = messageList.indexOf(message)

                            messageList.set(index, message)

                            adapter.changeMessages(messageList)
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()


                        }
                        is Response.Error -> {

                        }
                        else -> {

                        }

                    }

                } else if (type == RESPONSE_NULL) {

                }
                else if (type == ERROR) {

                }



            }

    }
```

why did this error occurred? of course,
only use of each `reference.removeEventListener(subscription)` and `channel.close()` also made same error. and I also really wonder it is fine to open callbackflow for a long time such as total application time. my app have chatting function so I should open it for a long time during using the app

Comment: Shouldn't `awaitClose` be placed outisde of the `try`/`catch`-block, so that it's always called? BTW, don't exceptions generated within a flow builder have to be propagated to the collector?

Comment: @Michael Hi bro. good question. but the exceptions was not propagated to and I don't know why TT.  and `awaitClose` outside of the try/catch also made same error

Answer (score 1):

You getting:

> awaitclose yourcallbackorlistener.cancel() ' should be used in the end of callbackflow block.

Because of the way you're removing the listener. So as the error says, you should remove the listener at the end of callbackflow block. That being said, you should not try to emit something else right after that. Since you get the error inside `onCancelled()` method, there is no need to add to use a try-catch block. So you only need to use:

```
override fun observeMessage(roomUid: String): Flow<Map<Int, Response<MessageEntity>>> = callbackFlow {
    val reference = databaseReference.child("messages").child(roomUid)

    val subscription = reference.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {

        override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            val message = snapshot.getValue(MessageEntity::class.java)

            if (message != null)
                trySend(mapOf(ADDED to Response.Success(message)))
            else
                trySend(mapOf(RESPONSE_NULL to Response.No(MessageEntity(uid = NULL))))

        }

        override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            val message = snapshot.getValue(MessageEntity::class.java)
            if (message != null)
                trySend(mapOf(CHANGED to Response.Success(message)))
            else
                trySend(mapOf(RESPONSE_NULL to Response.No(MessageEntity(uid = NULL))))

        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {}

        override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            //Handle error. 
        }
    } )

    awaitClose {
        reference.removeEventListener(subscription) //
        channel.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: it helped sir. but other issue about recyclerview occurred haha plz check

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74218159/android-kotlin-recyclerview-stackfromend-not-working

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: no, it was solved