# android kotlin recyclerview stackFromEnd not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

the app have a chatting function so I used 'stackFromEnd' method of recyclerview to show a last item of list firstly like other chatting app however, it not worked. it stopped in the middle of placing message items.

**MessageActivity OnCreate**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_message)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this


    val intent = intent

    room = intent.getSerializableExtra("room") as RoomEntity
    roomUid = room!!.uid

    other = intent.getSerializableExtra("other") as RoomMemberEntity
    ownUid = AppContext.uid

    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    layoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
    layoutManager.isSmoothScrollbarEnabled = true

    binding.recyclerMessages.recycledViewPool.setMaxRecycledViews(0,0)
    binding.recyclerMessages.layoutManager = layoutManager

    adapter = MessageAdapter(messageList, ownUid, other)
    binding.recyclerMessages.adapter = adapter

    binding.buttonSend.setOnClickListener {

        val text = binding.editMessage.text.toString()

        if (text.length > 0) {

            binding.editMessage.text!!.clear()

            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

                val sendResponse = viewModel.sendMessage(text, roomUid)

                when(sendResponse) {

                    is Response.Error -> {

                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {

                            Toast.makeText(this@MessageActivity,"message not sent due to the internet connection error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        }

                    }
                    else -> {

                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }



    binding.editMessage.doAfterTextChanged { text ->

        if (text!!.length > 0)
            binding.buttonSend.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        else
            binding.buttonSend.visibility = View.GONE

    }





}
```

**MessageActivity OnStart**

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {


            viewModel.fetchMessage(roomUid).collect {  fetchResponse->


                when (fetchResponse) {


                    is Response.Success -> {

                        val map = fetchResponse.data

                        val type = map.keys.first()

                        val message = map.get(type)

                        if (message != null) {


                            if (messageList.contains(message)) {

                                val index = messageList.indexOf(message)
                                messageList.set(index, message)

                            } else {

                                messageList.add(message)

                            }


                            if (type == ADDED) {

                                if (message.read == false && !message.sender.equals(ownUid)) {

                                    val readResponse = viewModel.readMessage(roomUid, message.uid)

                                    when(readResponse) {
                                        is Response.Error -> {

                                        }
                                        else -> {

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }

                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {

                                adapter.changeMessages(messageList)
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                            }

                        } else {

                        }

                    }
                    is Response.No -> {

                    }
                    is Response.Error -> {

                    }
                    else -> {

                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

**ViewModel**

```
private fun _fetchMessage (roomUid : String) : Flow<Response<Map<Int, MessageEntity>>> {

            val flow = repository.fetchMessage(roomUid).shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), 0)

            return flow
        }

        fun fetchMessage (roomUid: String) : Flow<Response<Map<Int, MessageEntity>>> {
            return _fetchMessage(roomUid)
        }
```

**DataSourceImpl**

```
val reference =
                            databaseReference.child("messages").child(roomUid)

                    val subscription =
                            reference.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {


                                    override fun onChildAdded(

                                            snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                                            previousChildName: String?

                                    ) {

                                            val message = snapshot.getValue(MessageEntity::class.java)

                                            if (message != null)
                                                    trySend(Response.Success(mapOf(ADDED to message )))
                                            else
                                                    trySend(Response.Success(mapOf(RESPONSE_NULL to MessageEntity())))


                                    }

                                    override fun onChildChanged(

                                            snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                                            previousChildName: String?

                                    ) {

                                            val message = snapshot.getValue(MessageEntity::class.java)

                                            if (message != null)
                                                    trySend(Response.Success(mapOf(CHANGED to message)))
                                            else
                                                    trySend(Response.Success(mapOf(RESPONSE_NULL to MessageEntity())))
                                    }

                                    override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                                    }

                                    override fun onChildMoved(

                                            snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                                            previousChildName: String?

                                    ) {

                                    }

                                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                                    }


                            } )


                    awaitClose {

                            reference.removeEventListener(subscription)
                            channel.close()
                    }
```

why this error occurred? is it due to callbackFlow??

**Issue (as you can see, the window does not show the end of messages. even usage of setStackFromEnd)**

[image]

**What I expected and wanted**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it stopped in the middle of placing message items"? Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo edited this post Alex! please check what I expected and wanted !

Comment: @AlexMamo ""it stopped in the middle of placing message items " is a wrong explanation.. sorry

Comment: You mean, you can't see the timestamp of last message, right ?

Comment: no sir, exactly, I expected the window shows the last item of messages (mean the latest message ) like other chatting app do when opening a chat room. however it showed me the middle message of total messages in opening its chat room

Answer (score 0):

Try this   `binding.rvChatMessage.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this ,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,true)` and remove stackfromend

Comment: it is a chatting app bro,,, reverseLayout should be not true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).